# How to remove just the window border?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I want to remove window border of my application made using `tkinter`.

I already used `overrideredirect(1)`, but it didn't satisfy me: it removed the window border as I wanted, but it also removed the icon on the task bar.

How can I just remove the window border?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is what you were asking for. I don't know if you can do this without using `Toplevel` or not, but here's a small example of what you could do to remove the window border and keep the icon in the taskbar.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0) #For icon
#root.lower()
root.iconify()
window = tk.Toplevel(root)
window.geometry("100x100") #Whatever size
window.overrideredirect(1) #Remove border
#window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
#Whatever buttons, etc 
close = tk.Button(window, text = "Close Window", command = lambda: root.destroy())
close.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)
window.mainloop()
```

You could then add buttons, labels, whatever you want to `window`

Comment: Wow! It works, Thank you very much. However, There's a problem that the program is **always on top** when I follow this code. Can you fix this problem?

Comment: Edited the post should fix your problem. and if it helped would you mind accepting?

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for me, on Windows, when I click on the icon in the task bar to minify everything is ok but when I click again to expand the windows doesn't appear on top.

Answer (score 17):

In case you're using a Canvas (because this thread is the first result in Google) and you have those borders annoying you, when you want your canvas to BE the window, the Canvas' constructor has a parameter that should suit your needs : `highlightthickness=0`

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)

w, h = 800, 500

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, highlightthickness=0)
# ...
# Do your things in your canvas
# ...

canvas.pack(fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do you create a draggable space in the canvas?

Comment: You can event listner to an area, and when the area is grabbed, and the the cursor is moving, change the position with `root.geometry` function.