# Tkinter winfo_screenwidth() returning slightly off value on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I've a tkinter based project running on Raspberry pi.

It works fine except, whenever I use `root.winfo_screenwidth()` method, it returns `1824` instead of `1980`. Same goes for height, ie, instead of returning `1080`, it returns `984`.

It works perfectly fine on my mac. Any idea, what am I missing here ?

Comment: Different desktop managers might give a different screen width to a "full-screen" application because some will have window borders. A mac's desktop environment does not have window borders.

Comment: @u8y7541: That was the only logical reason I could think of but I don't know where (or how) to look for the documentation of the same. If you can throw some references and convert it to an answer, that'd be great. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue with java applets on windows because windows has frame borders... Maybe you could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085533/how-to-remove-just-the-window-border

Comment: Interesting. Let me try out that option and get back.

Comment: might sound daft but i'm assuming you're expecting 1920x1080 because you are using a full hd screen, but on the pi you have options in `/boot/config.txt` for over/underscan, what values have you got set up for those? assuming it's a tv screen rather than a monitor the visible area is usually less than the nominal resolution. if you enable the option to disable overscan (not enabled by default) what results do you get?