# python full screen without console/borders

Tags: python, tkinter, console, fullscreen

I'm looking for a way to create a full screen window and not showing console (or the borders), and escape the full screen when 'escape' is pressed. I have tried to rename the extension from 'py' to 'pyw', but it didn't hide the side bar [as some suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python).

Here is my code to maximize the window, but it doesn't hide the console:

```
def __init__(master): #I'm using tkinter for my GUI
    master = master
    width, height = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
    master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
```

In addition, I need to use the script on both Mac and Windows, are they working differently if I need to hide the console?

I have tried `overrideredirect(True)`, but it doesn't allow me to use keyboard, which is required for my task. I also tried `wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)` , but it doesn't create exactly full screen, there's empty place at the top where the Mac Taskbar existed. [image]

So is there any way that allows me use full screen without the toolbar (MacOS), and the keyboard works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this for the screen resolution:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def escape(root):
        root.geometry("200x200")

def fullscreen(root):
        width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
        root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
        
master = Tk()
width, height = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
master.bind("<Escape>", lambda a :escape(master))
#Added this for fun, when you'll press F1 it will return to a full screen.
master.bind("<F1>", lambda b: fullscreen(master))
master.mainloop()
```

And this for no border (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085533/how-to-remove-just-the-window-border)):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0) #For icon
#root.lower()
root.iconify()
window = tk.Toplevel(root)
window.geometry("100x100") #Whatever size
window.overrideredirect(1) #Remove border
#window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
#Whatever buttons, etc 
close = tk.Button(window, text = "Close Window", command = lambda: root.destroy())
close.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)
window.mainloop()
```

The only solution for the console is to save the file as .pyw as you've already read. You can also try to override the Tk functions using `overrideredirect(1)` but that would be more complicated.

Hopefully this will help you, Yahli.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Yahli!  `overrideredirect(1)` does make the window to full screen. But it seems only works on Windows, but not on MacOS (top tool bar still shows). Do you know if there's anything work on Mac?

Comment: Glad I could help, consider accepting my answer if you found it good enough :) Regarding to your question - I'd try this `self.tk._w.wm_attributes(fullscreen='true')` and this `tl.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle", "style", tl._w, "plain", "none")` (I took it from [here](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/825270-tkinter-fullscreen-mac-os-x)). I don't own a Mac so unfortunately I can't debug those methods to know which one works best. Try them, and let me know :)